# free jqgrid 4.12 overlay issue when jqgrid inside modal dialog

Tags: jqgrid, dialog, modal-dialog, free-jqgrid

I use free jqgrid 4.12 and I use the jqgrid inside a modal dialog. When I select a row and click on the edit button, the edit dialog appear but I can't fill the field (it seems to be frozen).

Can you help me ?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ezy09ep/54/

```js
function OuvrirEcran()
{
    $("#Ecran").dialog("open");
};

$(function ()
{
    $("#Ecran").dialog(
    {
        dialogClass: 'Ecran',
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height:400,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'http://trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/jsonp/getjsonp.php?callback=?&qwery=longorders',
                mtype: "GET",
                datatype: "jsonp",
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'OrderID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
                    { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150, editable:true },
                    { label: 'Order Date', name: 'OrderDate', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'Freight', name: 'Freight', width: 150 },
                    { label:'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName', width: 150 }
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 480,
                height: 250,
                rowNum: 20,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });

            jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager', {
                del: true, add: false, edit: true}
            );

        },
        close:function () {}
    });
});  

$(document).ready(function () {
   OuvrirEcran();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting of the problem. It's very difficult to debug such problem. It's mostly now the problem in disabling of jQuery UI modal functionality for the Modal Dialog created by free jqGrid. If you comment `modal: true` in your demo you will see that the modal functionality of free jqGrid works correctly. Thus one need to find the way to inform jQuery UI don't block the input for Modal Dialog created by free jqGrid. I have to do some other changes in free jqGrid (better support of Bootstrap) and I'll come back to your problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid should utilize **ui-dialog** class when it creates modal dialog.

you will have to modify **jquery.jqGrid.min.js** file.

**As per version 5.0.0** ,

Just add **ui-dialog** class to follwing line,

```
modal: { modal: "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ",
```

e.g.

```
modal: { modal: "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-dialog",
```

**As per free jqGrid version**,

Add **ui-dialog** class to following line,

```
 dialog: {
                ...
                window: "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front",
                ...
```

e.g.

```
 dialog: {
                ...
                window: "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog",
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem is [the lines](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.11.4/ui/dialog.js#L804-L806) of code jQuery UI inside of internal method `_allowInteraction` of jQuery UI dialog:

```js
_allowInteraction: function( event ) {
    if ( $( event.target ).closest( ".ui-dialog" ).length ) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

It prevents interaction outside of any jQuery UI dialog.

I will include the following hack in free jqGrid code: I will add the lines

```js
if ($(h.w[0].ownerDocument).data("ui-dialog-overlays")) {
    h.w.addClass("ui-dialog"); // hack to allow input inside of jQuery UI modal
}
```

after [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.12.1/js/jqmodal.js#L186)

```js
h.w.css("z-index", z);
```

of `$.jqm.open()`. My tests shows that it fixes the problem.

I make some other changes in free jqGrid code now. Because of that I'll post the fix, which I described above, a little later. You can already text it using [jquery.jqgrid.4.12.1-jquerui-modal-fix.src.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/jquery.jqgrid.4.12.1-jquerui-modal-fix.src.js). You can test it on the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9ezy09ep/142/. Please use `http` and not `https` protocol in the JSFiddle, because I placed the fix on the server which don't support https.